# Code not working correctly

Tags: excel, excel-2013, vba

I have 4 subs that run consecutively. The first sub has `Call`s for the other three. There are two issues I am experiencing.

1. The `Copy_To_Template` sub completes all parts except, when I go
   into the workbook the data is getting copied to, the WGM worksheet
   is empty. Data was successfully copied to the other worksheets
   correctly.
2. The `Filter_AGD` sub is not removing rows at all. I will note that I am not sure if the `Filter_WGM` sub is working as there is no data in the worksheet. The `Filter_SWGM` **is** working as intended.

Below are all 4 sets of code:

```
Sub Copy_To_Template()
'
    ' The following is a list of the Source Workbooks and Worksheets

    Dim PRM1 As Workbook ' source workbook 1 contains current list of unassigned Problem Tasks
        Set PRM1 = Workbooks("BCRS-PTASKS Unassigned.csv")
    Dim PRM2 As Workbook ' source WorkBook 2 contains all assignment group information
        Set PRM2 = Workbooks("Problem WGM & WGL xref with description.xls")
    Dim PTASKS_Unassigned As Worksheet ' source WorkSheet
        Set PTASKS_Unassigned = PRM1.Sheets("BCRS-PTASKS Unassigned")
    Dim MANs As Worksheet
        Set MANs = PRM2.Sheets("Page 1")

    ' The following is a list of all the Destination workbooks and worksheets

    Dim PTASK_Template As Workbook ' destination WorkBook
        Set PTASK_Template = Workbooks("BCRS Unassigned Tasks Template.xlsm")
    Dim PTASK As Worksheet
        Set PTASK = PTASK_Template.Sheets("BCRS Unassigned Tasks")
    Dim WGMd As Worksheet
        Set WGMd = PTASK_Template.Sheets("WGM")
    Dim SWGMd As Worksheet
        Set SWGMd = PTASK_Template.Sheets("SWGM")
    Dim AGDd As Worksheet
        Set AGDd = PTASK_Template.Sheets("AGD")

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    ' Copy Unassigned Tasks

    Dim LRUPT As Long
    LRUPT = PTASKS_Unassigned.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim UPTRow As Long
    UPTRow = PTASK.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1 ' DestinationRow
    PTASKS_Unassigned.Range("A2:F" & LRUPT).Copy PTASK.Range("A" & UPTRow)

    PTASK.Range("A:A,B:B,C:C,D:D,E:E,F:F").Columns.AutoFit
    PTASK.Cells.WrapText = False

    ' Copy to WGM

    Dim LRWGM As Long
    LRWGM = MANs.Range("A" & MANs.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim WGMRow As Long
    WGMRow = WGMd.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1 ' DestinationRow
    MANs.Range("A2:E" & LRWGM).Copy WGMd.Range("A" & WGMRow)

    WGMd.Range("A:A,B:B,C:C,D:D,E:E").Columns.AutoFit
    WGMd.Cells.WrapText = False

    ' Copy to SWGM

    Dim LRSWGM As Long
    LRSWGM = MANs.Range("A" & MANs.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim SWGMRow As Long
    SWGMRow = SWGMd.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1 ' DestinationRow
    MANs.Range("A2:E" & LRSWGM).Copy SWGMd.Range("A" & SWGMRow)

    SWGMd.Range("A:A,B:B,C:C,D:D,E:E").Columns.AutoFit
    SWGMd.Cells.WrapText = False

    ' Copy to AGD

    Dim LRAGD As Long
    LRAGD = MANs.Range("A" & MANs.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim AGDRow As Long
    AGDRow = AGDd.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1 ' DestinationRow
    MANs.Range("A2:E" & LRAGD).Copy AGDd.Range("A" & AGDRow)

    AGDd.Range("A:A,B:B,C:C,D:D,E:E").Columns.AutoFit
    AGDd.Cells.WrapText = False

    Dim WB1 As Workbook
        Set WB1 = Workbooks("BCRS-PTASKS Unassigned.csv")

    Dim WB2 As Workbook
        Set WB2 = Workbooks("Problem WGM & WGL xref with description.xls")

    WB1.Close False
    WB2.Close False

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

    Call Filter_WGM
    Call Filter_SWGM
    Call Filter_AGD

End Sub

Sub Filter_WGM()
'

    Dim PTASK_Template As Workbook
        Set PTASK_Template = Workbooks("BCRS Unassigned Tasks Template.xlsm")
    Dim WGMd As Worksheet
        Set WGMd = PTASK_Template.Sheets("WGM")

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual


        With WGMd
        Dim LRMf As Long
            For LRMf = .Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
                If .Cells(LRMf, 3).Value <> "WorkGroup Manager" Then
                    .Rows(LRMf).Delete
                End If
            Next LRMf
        End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub

Sub Filter_SWGM()
'
    Dim PTASK_Template As Workbook
        Set PTASK_Template = Workbooks("BCRS Unassigned Tasks Template.xlsm")
    Dim SWGMd As Worksheet
        Set SWGMd = PTASK_Template.Sheets("SWGM")

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual


        With SWGMd
        Dim LRSf As Long
            For LRSf = .Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
                If .Cells(LRSf, 3).Value <> "Secondary WorkGroup Manager" Then
                    .Rows(LRSf).Delete
                End If
            Next LRSf
        End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub

Sub Filter_AGD()
'        
    Dim PTASK_Template As Workbook
        Set PTASK_Template = Workbooks("BCRS Unassigned Tasks Template.xlsm")
    Dim AGDd As Worksheet
        Set AGDd = PTASK_Template.Sheets("WGM")

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual


        With AGDd
        Dim LRDf As Long
            For LRDf = .Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
                If .Cells(LRDf, 3).Value <> "Director / DL" Then
                    .Rows(LRDf).Delete
                End If
            Next LRDf
        End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

Comment: You're sloppy. Go back to your [last question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37145774/rt-1004-method-range-of-object-worksheet-failed) and study your code again.

Comment: what @findwindow is referring to, I think, is the fact that `For LRDf = .Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row` should be `For LRDf = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row` (notice the `.` before `Rows.Count` - which was the same issue in your last question :)

Comment: @findwindow At first glance I was pretty mad at your comment, but after review, you are correct. I was sloppy. I see what you and Scott Holtzmanare saying. But, I have only just started using Excel 2013 (at work anyway) for coding. While I know there are some differences, I do not yet know all the caveats between 2007 and 2013.  With that said, is there a link you can provide that outlines some of the VBA differences between Excel versions? That would help ALOT.

Comment: I am mad at @ScottHoltzman but freedom of speech etc. Iron Man, you don't need to study differences between versions. Study each answer to the questions you ask so you don't ask them again. I think you asked a very similar question yesterday concerning `with`. That makes 3 times.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman I am assuming that I should do the same in the first sub where I am copying data. But I have to ask why data is copying to the SWGM and AGD worksheets, but not to the WGM worksheet?

Comment: `At first glance I was pretty mad at your comment` you would not be the first nor the last.  @findwindow can be a little crass with those he perceives as not learning from their mistakes, or post incomplete questions, or ... let's face it he likes to troll.  8P

Comment: @ScottCraner you know, 3 times in 2 days is pretty bad. Trolling? Me? Pffft, I think you got me confused with someone else.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman I made the suggested changes: `For LRDf = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row` . The end result was exactly the same as stated in my question. WGM is still showing no data, and the AGD worksheet did not get any rows deleted.

Comment: @IronMan It is really hard to find out the problems when we do not have access to the data.  Stop the code at some point then use F8 to step through the code line by line watching the Locals window to ensure that the variables are returning the expected values.  It will help to find any missing values.

Comment: @findwindow I am still learning VBA. over the last few months, I have learned quite a bit from this site. We recently upgraded (Friday) to Excel 2013. There are differences. I have till Friday to complete this little project. I did not immediately make the correlation between the answers because of the time pressure not allowing me to fully review yet.

Comment: @IronMan I can tell you're putting in effort. Time pressure sucks :/ Like Craner says, I can be `crass`. Please forgive me.

Comment: @findwindow Forgiven. Thank you. I am currently running through Scott Craner's suggestion looking at the Local Windows. So far, it seems to be running correctly. There are 13,000 rows to go through on the loops. Curious to see what happens after this first one. Will post results either way.

Comment: @ScottCraner So I ran through the code line by line as suggested and this is what I found. It ran through the first sub ok. The WGM worksheet had data. Then it ran through the second sub `Filter_WGM` and was deleting the rows it should have been (took awhile as there are 13,700 rows). Then it started the `Filter_SWGM` sub and ran as expected. However, when it finished this sub, it started again from the beginning of itself, but not before all the data in the WGM worksheet disappeared. There is no reason (that I can see) why this has occurred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't have found this if not for the debugging outlined in your last comment. So kudo's to all of the commenters for getting us to this point.

Your `Filter_AGD` sub is pointed at `WGM` worksheet, and wiping out the data there ...

```
Sub Filter_AGD()
'        
    Dim PTASK_Template As Workbook
        Set PTASK_Template = Workbooks("BCRS Unassigned Tasks Template.xlsm")
    Dim AGDd As Worksheet
        Set AGDd = PTASK_Template.Sheets("WGM")
```

Should be ...

```
Sub Filter_AGD()
'        
    Dim PTASK_Template As Workbook
        Set PTASK_Template = Workbooks("BCRS Unassigned Tasks Template.xlsm")
    Dim AGDd As Worksheet
        Set AGDd = PTASK_Template.Sheets("AGD")
```

Comment: Thanks. I obviously missed that. The pitfalls of copy/paste when you are in a hurry.

Comment: And I agree, everyone helped immensely in different ways. I love this site.